# How to merge two Api array results in to one in angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angular10

My first api array results are like below:

```
{name: 'ABC', state: 'AR', licenseNumber: '100108512'}
{name: 'DEF', state: 'KY', licenseNumber: '100108518'}
```

My second api array results are like below:

```
{rollnum: '20' name: 'KGF', state: 'NE', licenseNumber: '1628740'}
```

I would like to see the output like below

```
{name: 'ABC', state: 'AR', licenseNumber: '100108512'}
{name: 'DEF', state: 'KY', licenseNumber: '100108518'}
{name: 'KGF', state: 'NE', licenseNumber: '1628740' }
```

I have tried concat and spread syntax but it did not work may be because 1st api has 3 properties and 2nd api has 4 properties( but 3 properties are common in both).

Any suggestion to achieve above output in Angular 9 or above?

Comment: Does it matter that the second results have an extra prop? Unless you're iterating keys you won't encounter it in which case just `[...res1, ...res2]`. Otherwise simply destructure out the unwanted prop `const result = [...res1, ...res2.map(({ rollnum, ...res }) => res)];` Or do you mean you don't know the intersecting keys in advance?

Comment: remove the property you don't need then concat

Comment: Do you wanna keep `rollnum`? or ignore it

Comment: ignore the rollnum @PavanJadda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just map and concat:

```js
// example
let first = [{ name: 'ABC', state: 'AR', licenseNumber: '100108512' }, { name: 'DEF', state: 'KY', licenseNumber: '100108518' }];

// example
let second = [{ rollnum: '20', name: 'KGF', state: 'NE', licenseNumber: '1628740' }];

// use this common function to map the results in each set to the desired shared outcome
// if you have different logic or properties for mapping (e.g. map FirstName to Name) then make different mapping functions or change mapping logic in same function.
let mappingFunc = (item) => { return { name: item.name, state: item.state, licenseNumber: item.licenseNumber }; };

// final result contains desired result
const finalResult = first.map(mappingFunc).concat(second.map(mappingFunc))

console.log(finalResult);
```